# Renaming files with python to 1.jpg, 2.jpg, etc

Tags: python, python-2.7, batch-rename

First I would like to say I want to do this in python 2.7!

Hi, I have a folder full of images named 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg, etc. All the way up to 600.jpg.

I would like to rename them 600 higher, so 601.jpg, 602.jpg, 603.jpg, etc. All the way up to 1200.jpg.

I am honestly not quite sure where to start, so any help would be useful. It doesn't seam like it should be hard but I was not able to name them in ascending order. The best I got was 601.jpg, 601.jpg, and it was the same for every file.

This is what I have currently, it's been altered a few times, and now all I get is an error.

```
import os
path = '/Users/antse/OneDrive/Documents/Instagram/set_2'
files = os.listdir(path)
i = 601

for file in files:
    os.rename(os.path.join(path, file), os.path.join(path, str(i)+'.jpg'))
    i = i+1
```

Comment: Googling "python list files in directory" and "python rename file" should be a good starting point... shouldn't be too hard to find

Comment: _"The best I got was 601.jpg, 601.jpg, and it was the same for every file."_ Interesting. Please post the code that did this. Although it didn't work, it will make a useful starting-off point.

Comment: @Kevin I just added the code I had!

Comment: Possible duplicate of same code and question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37467561/renaming-multiple-files-in-a-directory-using-python).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the problems with your approach is that `listdir` doesn't come back in order from `1.jpg` ..., and it includes any other files or subdirectories. But there is no need to list the directory - you already know the pattern of what you want to change and its a hassle to deal with other files that may be there.

```
import os

path = '/Users/antse/OneDrive/Documents/Instagram/set_2'
for i in range(1, 601):
    old_name = os.path.join(path, '{}.jpg'.format(i))
    new_name = os.path.join(path, '{}.jpg'.format(i+600))
    try:
        os.rename(old_name, new_name)
    except OSError as e:
        print 'could not rename', old_name, e
```