# Renaming a file missing underscore at few places

Tags: python, python-os

Before posting this, i just refer the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37467561/renaming-multiple-files-in-a-directory-using-python) for renaming files in bulk, which is very useful to me while renaming a file from a given folder.

Before renaming, i do a validation check on file name from a excel sheet, if file present then rename it to it's respective name

[image]

I wrote a small code as below

```
for i in range(3, max_rw + 1):
 oCell = oSht.cell(column = 1, row = i)
 oCellr = oSht.cell(column = 2, row = i)
 nm = oCell.value
 renm = oCellr.value
 files = os.listdir(fldpth)


  for file in files:
     if nm in file:
        os.rename(os.path.join(fldpth, file), os.path.join(fldpth, renm+'.svg'))
```

But the output of the file in some place misleading as like below

1. Overridding previous value for below condition

   > if nm in file:

   Script might be doing global search, that mean in excel i have many items in name of "contact" i.e Contact Selected [*Row#3, as shown*], Contact unselected[*Row#4, as shown*] & many more including Contact[*Row#253*]

   If i am doing search from Row#3 to 12 then result is correct

   ***Contact unselected*** RENAMED TO ***Contact-unselected***

   If i do full search to max_column then result is wrong

   ***Contact unselected*** RENAMED TO ***contact***
2. Underscore is missing in many places like

   ***Group selected*** RENAMED TO ***Group Selected***

   ***History selected*** RENAMED TO ***History Selected***

   ***Map selected*** RENAMED TO ***Map Selected***

Comment: At what indentation level is the second for `for file in files` is inside or outside the first.

Comment: Inside the first. Corrected now.

Comment: I suppose that in the last 3 lines you are trying to implement `os.path.exists`, aren't you?

Comment: Substitute your `for file in files: if nm in file` with `os.path.exists` and `os.rename` with `print(nm, renm)` - what do you see?

Comment: I tried with print(nm,"-->"+renm), it's gives me result as Contact Selected -->contact_selected || Contact unselected -->Contact-unselected

Comment: Try if nm == file: in place of if nm in file:.

Comment: It is failing for nm == file, that mean no file is getting renamed

Comment: @Kapi, which means that names in excel and names in files do not match. You should check and try removing white spaces or any special characters present in nm.