# Using Python to rename files in different folders

Tags: python, copy, rename, file-rename

I have thousands of files to be renamed in several subfolders in the main folder. The existing file name, path, and the new file name are available in an excel file.
I have been using Excel VBA to do this earlier and now I am into Python and would like to accomplish this task using Python.

I am looking for a solution as below:

1. Renaming the files in the same place
2. Copying the files with folders to a new location and rename there to preserver the originals.

Please provide your valuable inputs.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You should probably take a look at `os`, `glob` and `shutil` modules, they have all the necessary functionality.

Comment: `pathlib` is better as it intuitively incorporates the modules mentioned above

Comment: If you have working VBA code, a starting point can be just rewriting that code with Python commands. If that gives you trouble, share your code here and get some answers.

Comment: You can check these out [renaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37467561/renaming-multiple-files-in-a-directory-using-python) and [copying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123198/how-do-i-copy-a-file-in-python)