# How to rename files in a folder using Python's pathlib module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-rename, pathlib

I need help renaming .jpg files in my folder to add the same prefix, 'cat_'. For example, "070.jpg" should be renamed to "cat_070.jpg".

The files are located within the Cat folder:

```
from pathlib import Path
p = Path('C:\\Users\\me\\Jupiter_Notebooks\\Dataset\\Train\\Cat\\')
```

I don't quite see how to do it. The code below is wrong because it does not 'look into' the files in this directory:

```
p.rename(Path(p.parent, 'cat_' + p.suffix))
```

I have also unsuccessfully tried this:

```
import os
from os import rename
from os import listdir

# Get path 
cwd = "C:\\Users\\me\\Jupiter_Notebooks\\Dataset\\Train\\Cat"

# Get all files in dir
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(cwd) if isfile(join(cwd, f))]


for file in onlyfiles:

    # Get the current format
    if file[-4:]==(".jpg"):
        s = file[1]  

    # Change format and get new filename
    s[1] = 'cat'
    s = '_'.join(s)

    # Rename file
    os.rename(file, s)
    print(f"Renamed {file} to {s}")


FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Users\\me\\Jupiter_Notebooks\\Dataset\\Train\\Cat\\'
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```py
from pathlib import Path

img_dir = Path('C:\\Users\\me\\Jupiter_Notebooks\\Dataset\\Train\\Cat\\')  # path to folder with images
for img_path in img_dir.glob('*.jpg'):  # iterate over all .jpg images in img_dir
    new_name = f'cat_{img_path.stem}{img_path.suffix}'  # or directly: f'cat_{img_path.name}'
    img_path.rename(img_dir / new_name)
    print(f'Renamed `{img_path.name}` to `{new_name}`')
```

`pathlib` also supports renaming files, so the `os` module is not even needed here.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can rename a file with pathlib using the [rename](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rename) and [with_name](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.with_name) functions:

```
import pathlib,datetime
path = pathlib.Path('./file_to_rename.txt').absolute()
print(path.with_name(f"{path.stem.replace('re','un')}{path.suffix}"))
# C:\Users\User\Desktop\folder\file_to_unname.txt
path.rename(path.with_name(path.with_name(f"{path.stem.replace('re','un')}{path.suffix}")))
```

Answer (score -3):

use `pathlib.Path.iterdir()` to rename all files in a directory

```
for path in pathlib.Path("a_directory").iterdir():
    if path.is_file():
        old_name = path. stem. original filename.
        old_extension = path. suffix. original file extension.
        directory = path.parent. ...
        new_name = "text" + old_name + old_extension.
        path.rename(pathlib.
```

Comment: Please format your code block correctly and remove the line numbers.

Comment: This code doesn't even run because of syntax errors